# How to get an IntProperty to update a function?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

Or in this case how to get the integer prop(MyInt) to activate the selectTrack() function each time the integer prop(MyInt) is updated?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *

class UIPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Export EDL"
    bl_space_type = "SEQUENCE_EDITOR"

    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene
        layout.label(text=" Select Video Channel: ")
        layout.prop(scn, 'MyInt', icon='BLENDER', toggle=True)

# Select Track by batFINGER       
def selectTrack():        

    context = bpy.context
    scene = context.scene
    active_channel = bpy.context.scene.MyInt    
    print("Active Channel: "+str(active_channel))

    sed = scene.sequence_editor
    # if active strip isn't in active_channel set to None.
    if getattr(sed.active_strip, "channel", -1) != active_channel:
        sed.active_strip = None

    sequences = sed.sequences_all
    # select all strips in active channel
    for strip in sequences:
        strip.select = strip.channel == active_channel  

def initSceneProperties(scn):
    bpy.types.Scene.MyInt = IntProperty(
        name = "Channel", 
        description = "Select Channel for Video Export",
        min = 1,
        max = 32,
        update=selectTrack())
    scn['MyInt'] = 1
    return

#    Registration
bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code Fix**

Made some changes to get this running.  Pretty sure the HORRIBLE `register_module` is being phased out, wrote a `register` and `unregister` method with no parameters. This is what an addon expects to see, and is called when an addon is enabled.

The update method is defined on the property `update=method` without the braces, ie it's the function definition, not the result of the called method (`method()`).  The update method has two parameters, `self` and `context`.  The self in this case will the the scene instance, since the property is defined on the `Scene` class.

Lastly it's standard to use `xxx_yyy` for method and property names, and `XxxYyy` for class names.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty

class UIPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Export EDL"
    bl_space_type = "SEQUENCE_EDITOR"

    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene
        layout.label(text=" Select Video Channel: ")
        layout.prop(scn, "my_int", icon='BLENDER', toggle=True)


def change_channel(self, context):        

    active_channel = self.my_int    
    print("Active Channel: "+str(active_channel))

    sed = self.sequence_editor
    # if active strip isn't in active_channel set to None.
    if getattr(sed.active_strip, "channel", -1) != active_channel:
        sed.active_strip = None

    sequences = sed.sequences_all
    # select all strips in active channel
    for strip in sequences:
        strip.select = strip.channel == active_channel  

#    Registration
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(UIPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_int = IntProperty(
        name = "Channel", 
        description = "Select Channel for Video Export",
        min=1,
        max=32,
        default=1,
        update=change_channel)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UIPanel)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: So much to learn here. Thank you. The code was based on the old(but usefull) cookbook https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface#Interface It probably needs an update, if it's for 2.6.

Comment: Np.. yep recall using that myself.  One major issue with the old code will be restricted context when registering addons.  In restricted context scene and other context members are not available (security being the reason).  You can define a class property, but not set its value.  (personally I'd like to see small scripting examples in the manual)

Comment: One could hope for better documentation. I spend most of the time googling for code examples which I can piece together for what I need to code. Autoitscript has a good combination of descriptions and working examples in their docs. Something like that would be a good start. Anyway how do I set the default value of my_int(in my example it was 1)?

Comment: Use `default=1` in property definition. Edited answer.